# file explorer in android

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android. I need to list available files in device or SDCard in the android emulator 1.5.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use normal Java File IO operations(see [class-documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html))

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
String pathToSdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
new File(pathToSdCard ).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had posted this on another page. Its a late answer but I worked on creating an android file explorer recently. https://github.com/mburman/Android-File-Explore

Its really straightforward. Essentially its just 1 file that you would need to integrate into your application.