# How can I browse internal and external storage (sdcard) of android by clicking on photo?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have this scenerio

http://www.cubixshade.com/images/test_photo.jpg

Open above url and I want an interface when photo box is clicked to browse sdcard images ?

does android sdk provide any component which browse image from sd card and show in android appplication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are 2 scenario to pick image from SD-card images.

1. Open native gallery and pick image from it (Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309217/379693) answer)
2. User-defined gallery by defining custom adapter for your ListView/GridView, pick image from it (check this example: [Android – Select multiple photos from Gallery](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/))

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
String pathToSdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
new File(pathToSdCard ).list();
```

and also Check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895640/file-explorer-in-android)

Thanks